# Calculate the time spent by a user creating changeset

Tags: openstreetmap, time

Is there a way to calculate the time spent by a user while creating a changeset?

1. The OSM Changeset file (i.e. map.osm) has timestamp, changeset, user
   fields. Can the timestamp filed values be compared to find out
   the total time spend by specific user?
2. Also, is there a way to do so using [osmfilter](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmfilter)?

Comment: Another crosspost: https://forum.openstreetmap.org/viewtopic.php?id=57435

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. The timestamp only shows when the changes were uploaded. No one knows when the user started working on them.